# How can i find the timestamp for the next starting minute?

Tags: php, time

I want to do something like this

```
strtotime("next starting minute");
```

If the current time is 15:23:21, i want to get 15:24:00

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `strtotime()` but use `time()` and `ceil()`.

```
$next_minute_timestamp = ceil(time()/60)*60;
```

This way, easy calculated you will always get the timestamp for the next minute. Because I divide the timestamp by 60, it will return the number of minutes. Ceiling this will get you the next minute. Then the timestamp again is multiplied by 60 to get the seconds, which is the timestamp you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
$timestamp = mktime(date('H'), date('i') + 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime(date('H') . ":" . (date('i') + 1) . ":00");`

Answer (score 0):

Get the time, subtract the seconds, add 60 seconds for one minute:

```
$timestamp = time()-(time()%60)+60;
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution , it worked for me.

$nexminute = date("H:i", time()+60).":00";